# $addToSet - Mongo functionality

Tags: ruby, mongodb

If I use $addToSet to add data which was earliar deleted from the same collection, in that case will it that entry again?

Query:
XYZCollection.collection.update_one({ 'm_id' => BSON::ObjectId.from_string(m_id), 'p_id' => BSON::ObjectId.from_string(p_id) }, { '$addToSet' => { 'c_ids' => c_id } })

Example I added c_id once, then deleted it, then I tried to re-add again, what will happen, will it be added in the XYZCollection?

Comment: $addToSet add element  to array in document if the element do not exist already , this is all it can do ...

Comment: so if we have deleted an element first, then it should add it correct??, since that element is not present, but its not being added.

Comment: Add example document

Comment: I am using this query in ruby

Comment: Okey , I am also using my fork at lunch ;) , but I need to know how your documents looks like to understand why your query do not work :)

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fe4456c3a368484e01d6bd"),
    "c_name" : "test_name",
    "m_id" : ObjectId("4bc8c421017a3c122d083836"),
    "p_id" : ObjectId("4bc88b21017a3c122d001059"),
    "c_ids" : [ 
        ObjectId("61b9e16b51e6ab00250da31b"), 
        ObjectId("61b9e1fc51e6ab00250da472"), 
        ObjectId("61c171a7907f26002d6485c8"), 
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

$addToSet behaviour:

1. When you add new element to array if do not exist is is added to the array:

[playground adding new element:](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SLeip8gB1PZ)

2. When you add new element to array that already exist , the operation do not do anything :

[playground adding element that already exists](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VUSxqTdFbQz)

3. If the field key do not exist in the document , it will be created with single array element.

[playgrouund adding array field in document where the field do not yet exist](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ig3pJuP9uXL)

4. When you remove element you need to remove with $pull operation:

[playground pull from array](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8UV1ociYtcp)

Comment: But if I deleted the entry from c_id array before inserting that same id, it again in it using addToSet, why is it not adding, it should add right?  it does not add.

Comment: the correct behaviour is to add it if the same element was removed previously ... , there must be something in your code ...

Comment: This unless you are bundling multiple operations in ttansaction and transaction has not been commited ...

Comment: It works properly for any new data added, only failing for this particular where entry is deleted and added again.